# What is pbm_commnotify event in PowerBuilder?

Tags: events, powerbuilder

What is pbm_commnotify event in PowerBuilder? How can it be triggered?

```
global type some_type from Window
...
event commnotify pbm_commnotify
...
end type

on commnotify;
...
end on;
```

I am working for a project that requires us to convert a system written in Powerbuilder many years ago into a web application. I am new to Powerbuilder and really have no idea how this type of event can be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most `pbm_xxx` event IDs in PowerScript map to `wm_Xxx` in Win16/Win32.

Your example:

Code for event `commnotify` is the "event handler" for Win32 message `WM_CommNotify`.

Be aware:

- Some PowerScript event IDs don't map to Win16/Win32 messages.
- You may encounter *unmapped* PowerScript events (events without event IDs).
- `pbm_custom01`, `pbm_custom02`, ... map to `WM_User`, (`WM_User + 1`), ...*

Comment: From this [forum answer](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?270988-wm_commnotify&s=db340c4754dbcecdde5ee7aaa765b300&p=842370#post842370) WM_COMMNOTIFY seems to be rather an obsolete Win16 message and is no more documented by Microsoft on MSDN